# How to correct the incomplete for loop output?

Tags: python

My script works perfectly but it runs only for the first entry instead of the whole array. The script is as below:

```
import numpy as np 
from obspy import read
from obspy.clients.fdsn import Client
from obspy import UTCDateTime
from datetime import datetime  
from datetime import timedelta 
import pandas as pd 

client = Client("IRIS")
dd=[]
df = pd.read_csv('T.txt')
for i in df:
    time = UTCDateTime(i)
    starttime = time -timedelta(minutes=5)
    endtime = time + timedelta(minutes=6)
    net = "OO"
    sta = "AXCC1"
    loc = "*"
    chan = "HHZ"
    st = client.get_waveforms(net, sta, loc, chan, starttime, endtime, attach_response= True)
    st[0].stats.sampling_rate
    data=st[0].data
    a=max(data)
    #a.append(dd)
    dd.append(float(a))
print(a)
```

The format of data in the text file is as below:

```
2015-02-13T18:59:12.230Z
2015-02-16T23:06:28.270Z
2015-03-29T23:48:31.010Z
2015-04-24T13:56:15.180Z
2015-04-25T06:11:25.950Z
2015-04-26T07:09:10.670Z
2015-04-30T10:45:02.930Z
2015-05-01T08:06:03.480Z
2015-05-05T01:44:06.380Z
2015-05-07T07:10:19.590Z
```

the code gives output for only the first entry.

Comment: You got some answers below so just one additional comment you probably want to read the CSV using `df = pd.read_csv('T.txt',header=None)` otherwise the first row of the text file will be treated as the CSV header row.

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.iterrows()` instead of just `df`:

```
...
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    time = UTCDateTime(i)
    starttime = time -timedelta(minutes=5)
    ...
```

Comment: It needs to be `iterrows()`

Comment: Updated to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can write as below:

```
import numpy as np 
from obspy import read
from obspy.clients.fdsn import Client
from obspy import UTCDateTime
from datetime import datetime  
from datetime import timedelta 
import pandas as pd 

client = Client("IRIS")
dd=[]
df = pd.read_csv('T.txt')
for i in df:
    time = UTCDateTime(i)
    starttime = time -timedelta(minutes=5)
    endtime = time + timedelta(minutes=6)
    net = "OO"
    sta = "AXCC1"
    loc = "*"
    chan = "HHZ"
    st = client.get_waveforms(net, sta, loc, chan, starttime, endtime, attach_response= True)
    st[0].stats.sampling_rate
    data=st[0].data
    a=max(data)
    #a.append(dd)
    dd.append(float(a))
    print(a)
```